# Can someone tell me why my header isn't showing up asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2013

so im trying to set up a header for my div but for some the header wont display the bacground colour:

here is my style code :

```
   .HeaderClass
         {
             background-color:#26a2b0;
             width :800px;
             height : 150px;
         }
```

and here is my div code:

```
 <div class ="Header">
         emu
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


         </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
     </div>
```

Comment: Header != .HeaderClass ;-)

Comment: Oh so now that works :') thanks nick

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS file clearly states that the class name should be `HeaderClass`, but your HTML uses `Header`.

Either change your HTML to:

```
<div class="HeaderClass">
    ...
</div>
```

, or change your CSS to:

```
.Header
{
    ...
}
```